# How get public methods of a java class and then run it?

Tags: java

I have a java class. I want get all methods of this class that are public and defined in the class. My code is as follows:

```
public class Class1
{
    private String a;
    private String b;


    public void setA(String a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(String b){
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA(){
        return a;
   }

    private String getB(){
        return b;
    }
}
```

I want Only to get `setA`, `setB`, and `getA` and then run this methods.

How do I do?

Comment: `Class1.class.getMethods()` ?

Comment: this method return all of class methods

Comment: @assylias answer +  call `invoke()` on all the methods of the method array returned by the method call. You will have to pass the object on which these methods should be called

Comment: @mortezamalvandi - Nope. `getDeclaredMethods()` will return all methods (public / private / protected).. `getMethods()` will return only public methods

Comment: You should see the [reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) API

Comment: @TheLostMind - getMethods() get super class methods

Comment: @mortezamalvandi - Ya.. In that case use Ruchira's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [invoke()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) with reflection.

```
Class1 class1=new Class1();
Method[] methods=class1.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for(Method i:methods){
   if (Modifier.isPublic(i.getModifiers())) {
     try {
       i.invoke(class1, "a");
     } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: this get private methods too.

Comment: use `getMethods()` for getting *only public* methods.. `getDeclaredMethods()` returns all methods

Comment: YA.. This will do .. +1 :)

Comment: @mortezamalvandi In here already doing it.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Comment: Class1 point = new Class1(); Class1 p = piont.getClass(); ...[your code] ... i.invoke(p, point);

Answer (score 2):

Get all accessible public methods using `getMethods`, it will include all methods of `Object` class also, than you can only view `Class1` public methods by checking `getDeclaringClass()`

```
 Class c = Class1.class;
 Method[] pubMeth = c.getMethods();
 for(Method m : pubMeth){
    if(m.getDeclaringClass() == c){ // Only Class1 pub methods
      System.out.println(m.getName());
    }
 }
```